# How to show main menu links based on user roles?

Tags: 7, users

I am showing menu items and I want to show some links to Anonymous user only and some links to Authenticate user.

It it possible to accomplish this in Drupal 7? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

Meet [Menu Per Role Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role)

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items1 based on user
>   roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module—just activate both
>   modules and edit a menu item as usual.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Menu item visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module.

> This module exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings
>   for menu links.

Comment: it causes problem  like we cannt move  menu items, it has some bugs

Answer (score 2):

Also go for [Custom Menu Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_menu_perms)

It allows for the permission used to access any menu item on the system to be overridden.

It allows for custom permissions (see hook_permission()) to be created through the admin interface. These permissions can be used the same as any permissions created in a module using hook_permission() - ie in modules, templates, and in hook_menu() callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install any contributed module. Create two menus one for anonymous and one for authenticated. Assign them to two blocks. (Menu Blocks).

Now give access permissions to those Blocks accordingly. One Block to anonymous and one for authenticated.

So the menu links added for them will be visible based on their role